# Django: remove all m2m relations

Tags: django

if I have two simple models:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
```

given a Post object with a number of Tags `add`ed to it, I know hot to remove any of them, but how to do a mass remove (remove all)? Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Have you tried [`Post.tags.clear()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)?

Comment: It need to access the `through` model to do the query on the manager of the relationship.
 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through  
.... See my answer in this thread

Answer (score -3):

If you need to delete only the relationship for all instance between 2 models then you can do that by accessing the Manager of the relationship table. The m2m relationship table can be accessed via `MyModel.relations.through` so for deleting the relationships it becomes easy:

```
MyModel.relations.through.objects.all().delete()
```

reference:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through

Comment: You misread the question: "given a Post object" means that pistacchio wants to **delete only the relations to that one specific `Post`,** not every relation between every `Post` and `Tag` in the entire database. In this case, calling `.tags.clear()` on the `Post` object is exactly what pistacchio wants.

Comment: Thanks you to correct me. The title was misleading and I was looking for doing what I have done so I updated this thread.