# How to restrict the deletion of PSQL table rows in Django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm working on a project using Django 1.9 + django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2

On one model I have a m2m relationship:

```
class School(models.Model):
    ...
    admins = models.ManyToManyField(
        User,
        verbose_name=_("admins"),
        related_name="admins",
        blank=True
    )
    ...
```

This, of course, ends up creating a "school_admins" table on the DB.
with 3 columns (id, school_id, user_id)

I need to restrict the deletion of rows on this table so they only can be deleted from a specific endpoint.
I tried to do this by adding a m2m_changed signal but there is a [limitation](https://github.com/django/django/commit/9d104a21e20f9c5ec41d19fd919d0e808aa13dba) that makes this impossible

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Try it: [django-remove-all-m2m-relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914066/django-remove-all-m2m-relations)   `School.admins.clear()`

Comment: If you want to `limit` what the user can do in the admin site you can maybe use this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.form